# Connecting to C# asp.net using Ksoap2 in Android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm trying to connect to my asp web service and get the response using this codes. It gives no error but it's not connecting to my web service either. Can anyone point my mistake? thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MyFirstWebMethod";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "MyFirstWebMethod";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:1595/test.asmx";
    String name = "Test";
    String last = "Me";
    String result;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btngo)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME); 
                 request.addProperty("name", name);
                 request.addProperty("last", last);
                 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                 envelope.dotNet=true;
                 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
                 HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
                 try {
                 ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                 SoapObject response  = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                 result = response.getProperty(1).toString();

                 } 
                 catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }   

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

this is what the log cat said

```
11-08 13:15:00.344: I/Choreographer(977): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-08 13:15:00.405: W/System.err(977): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-08 13:15:00.405: W/System.err(977):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
11-08 13:15:00.413: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:75)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:136)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
11-08 13:15:00.437: W/System.err(977):  at com.example.xmlparser.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-08 13:15:00.443: W/System.err(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 13:15:00.453: W/System.err(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 13:15:00.453: W/System.err(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-08 13:15:00.453: W/System.err(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-08 13:15:00.453: W/System.err(977):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 13:15:00.618: I/Choreographer(977): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Please share your stacktrace .

Comment: According to logs your problem not with ksoap. You are doing networking on UI thread which is forbidden by default on newer android versions. Try Shyam's solution or look here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 2):

```
Sucessful Connection with Asp.net Webservice-----
package ProductVerificationCard.in;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdminLogin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn_ok;
    TextView textView;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Login";

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/new/WebService.asmx";
    String s;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                        OPERATION_NAME);

                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                        try

                        {

                        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        Object response = envelope.getResponse();

                        //textView.setText(response.toString());
                         s=response.toString();
                         if(s=="true")
                         {
                             Intent intent=new Intent(AdminLogin.this,MenuForm.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                         }

                         else
                         {
                             textView.setText("Enter Valid Username or Password");
                         }
                        }

                        catch (Exception exception)

                        {

                        textView.setText(exception.toString());

                        }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I thinks we have the same way connecting in web service but its not working for me

Comment: where is Asyntask in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Do u think webservice at "http://10.0.2.2:1595" will be accessible publicly ?(In my option NO). Try to host it on public IP and  then try . Your code seems to be OK .

Comment: it's just a localhost sir. I really don't know if I'm Connecting to my web service or not because I'n not getting any response from it